# Is there django auth backend to authorize by temporary links?

Tags: django, authentication

I am searching a backend to authorize users by email without password. This backend should send them temprary authentication links to an inbox.

Is there any solution or I should write it myself?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like such available, so i fear you have to write it yourself.

As i understand, you can take lets say an "authentication_code" from a url you sent to user's mailbox.

```
http://example.net/allow/xauthcodex/
```

You can get 'xauthcodex' in view, which will later call `authenticate()` and then `login()`.

You would have to write your own authentication backend though, that will take this `auth_code`, will check against it, and would return respective user, for `login()` function to work. I am assuming `auth_code` is unique for user.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to implement it. Just searching exiting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the http://bitbucket.org/lorien/django-urlauth/

Comment: I already wrote such application: http://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-link-auth

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote such application: http://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-link-auth